# virtual function overridden and private, public specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

I got surprised that a `public`(or `private`) virtual function can be overridden by a `private`(or `public`) virtual function. See below,

```
class C{
    public:
    virtual void f(){cout<<"C"<<endl;}
    void g(){f();}

};
class D:public C{
  private:
  virtual void f(){cout<<"D"<<endl;}
};

int main(){
  C * c = new D;
  c->g();
  return 0;
}
```

the code outputs `D`. I thought virtual function can **only** be overridden in the derived class with the same access specifier as in the base class, but this is apparently not how the above code works, am I observing something wrong?  Why the access specifiers (`public`, `protected` and `private`) don't put restrictions on how the virtual function is overridden?

Comment: No, you are observing things correctly and you thought wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++11 Standard does not mention anything about the access specifiers of virtual functions in **10.3 Virtual Functions**, at least I cannot find any.

Given that, `D::f()` is not directly accessible through an object or pointer of type `D`.

```
D* dPtr = new D;
dPtr->f();      // Does not work.
```

The following works:

```
C* cPtr = new D;
cPtr->f();
```

since `C::f()` is a public member function of `C`.

**Update**

Upon further investigation, I found the following:

> **11.5 Access to virtual functions**
>
> 1 The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by the rules for a function that later overrides it. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> class B {
> public:
>   virtual int f();
> };
>
> class D : public B {
> private:
>   int f();
> };
>
> void f() {
>   D d;
>   B* pb = &d;
>   D* pd = &d;
>   pb->f();  // OK: B::f() is public,
>             // D::f() is invoked
>   pd->f();  // error: D::f() is private
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

Comment: N4296 says (a footnote in 10.3): "Access control (Clause 11) is not considered in determining overriding."

Comment: @AlexD, that must've been added to C++14 after C++11 was finalized. Good to know that they made that explicit.